# How do I stop incrementing a value to a certain point

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

What I created was a project where a Servo Motor turns to a certain LDR sensor based off of if there is light on a certain ldr sensor. However once my servo motor reaches to a point after a second or two it randomly starts spinning.

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

servo = 11
west_ldr = 21
east_ldr = 20

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)

gpio.setup(west_ldr, gpio.IN)
gpio.setup(east_ldr, gpio.IN)
gpio.setup(servo, gpio.OUT)

pwm = gpio.PWM(11, 50)
pwm.start(0)

a=90

def servo(angle):
duty_cycle = angle*(1/18)+2
pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty_cycle)
time.sleep(.5)

servo(a)

while True:
    read_west = gpio.input(west_ldr)
    read_east = gpio.input(east_ldr)

    if read_west == 0 and read_east == 0:
        servo(a)
    
    if read_west == 1:
        print("West Led has no sunshine")

    else:
        print("West Led has sunshine")
        a = a-5

    if read_east == 1:
        print("East Led has no sunshine")
    
    else:
        print("East Led has sunshine")
        a = a+5

    servo(a)
```

Comment: `a = min(a+5, a_limit)` will prevent `a` from going over `a_limit`

Comment: You never turn off the motor.  If this is like most motors, the duty cycle determines how FAST it spins, not how FAR it will go.  You never turn off the motor.  And the way your code reads, if both GPIOs read zero, you write to the servo, then decrease a by 5, then increase a by 5, then set the servo again.  I don't think this code really does what you want.

Comment: What does 'randomly start spinning' mean? Is it oscillating every .5 seconds by +/-  5 degrees?  Agree would look at your WHILE loop.  Don't think you need the first IF statement.  If you add print(a) in to the bottom of the WHILE loop does it show the value oscillating?